# Use a button with JQuery to collapse a div

Tags: javascript

I found this code on jsfiddle and I am trying to get it to work on my page.

Here is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/AfCdg/2/

Here is the code on JSFiddle:

```
<div data-role="page">

     <div data-role="header" id="header">
         <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
         <h1>Logo</h1>
         <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="search" id="searchButton">Buscar</a>
     </div>

     <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="searchForm" data-collapsed="true">
            <h3>tester</h3>
            <p>This is some text, cool</p>
        </div><!-- end searchform-->
     </div><!-- end content-->
</div><!-- end page-->

$(document).ready(function(){

      $('#searchButton').live('click', function(event, ui) {
        $("#searchForm").toggle();
      });

});
```

and here is my code:

```
<div data-role="header" id="header"><a href="#" data-role="button" id="CollapseButton">Refund Policy</a></div>

<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="refund" data-collapsed="true">
```

and my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#CollapseButton').live('click', function (event, ui) {
        $("#refund").toggle();

        setTimeout(function () {
            var divPosition = $('#refund').offset();

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: divPosition.top }, "fast");
        }, 200);
    });

});
```

Currently the div does not start collapsed nor does it toggle when I click on the a href button.  What am I missing?

Here are the only errors I receive in the Chrome console and neither looks relevant to me.

[image]

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @j08691, Using Chrome developer console I do not see any errors.  Is there another place I should check.  Would the errors prevent it from started collapsed as well?

Comment: In your code you attach live to $('#CollapseButton') but in your example you have $('#searchButton')

The id of **Buscar** link has been changed?

Comment: It's showing collapsed by default for me, also I don't think [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) does what you think it does.

Comment: @DjLeChuck  I changed the id to my button.  I don't know what you mean by the id of buscar link?

Do you mean did I change the link id? if you do then yes I did. put my code reflects that as well.

Comment: You said you've changed `<div data-role="collapsible" id="refund" data-collapsed="true">` not `<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="search" id="searchButton">Buscar</a>`

Comment: @APAD1, where does it show collapsed by default? in jsfiddle? I am trying it in my MVC project and it doesn't work.  I think toggle() will collapse or expand the div depending on the what it is currently.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you show us all of your code/html please?

Comment: @nik0lias I updated to include the button now.  I forgot to put the code tag around it initially

Answer (score 0):

Your id of the button is searchButton

Change your code to the new id, or match them to your html either way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#searchButton').live('click', function (event, ui) {
    $("#refund").toggle();

    setTimeout(function () {
        var divPosition = $('#refund').offset();

        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: divPosition.top }, "fast");
    }, 200);
});
```

});

```
 <div data-role="header" id="header">
     <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
     <h1>Logo</h1>
     <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="search" id="searchButton">Buscar</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: I think that is just for the jsfiddle code, which is the code he was modeling his own after. He didn't post his own button, so we don't know what the id for that is.

Comment: I've just seen the comments to the question! I'll monitor it and delete/edit accordinly!

Comment: Sorry I fixed it now.  I did post the button but since I forgot to put the code tag around the code, it only showed as 'Refund Policy'

Comment: Not a problem! Quick fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$('#searchButton').live('click', ...` to `$('#searchButton').on('click', ...`

https://jsfiddle.net/o3mk90xq/

Also, note the check for whether or not the element is hidden when it first loads, in order to hide it initially.

```
if (!$("#refund").is(':hidden')) {
    $("#refund").hide();
}
```

Comment: e-e thank you for the assistance.  Oddly it works in the jsfiddle but the same exact code does not work in my project.  Is there something else I should post? or try something else?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: 2.0 I have installed

Comment: I just added a pic with the errors. However, they do not look relevant to me.  Do they look relevant to you?

Comment: you're getting an error for `$nav_a.scrolly`, which is probably stopping execution before it gets to the code you've asked about, which is why it's not working for you. Try commenting that code out and see if the toggle works.

Comment: I feel like I am in the twighlight zone. I did a search for that code in my entire solution and it could not find it.

Comment: According to the image you posted it is in init.js on line 73. you can also click that and it will show you in dev tools

Comment: Thank you e-e.  I got rid of that Javascript error and now only have the font error.  However, it still is not working on my machine.  I copied all my html and my javascript in to JSFiddle and it works in JSFIddle but will not work in my project.  Something in my machine must be conflicting.  Should I upgrade my jquery to 2.2? because that is the version that JSfiddle is using for that fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103994/discussion-between-e-e-and-djblois).